# How to handle target window already closed error in selenium automation

Tags: selenium-webdriver

While running script for login page, I am Getting error of targeted window already closed

My code is

Webdriver d = new chromedriver();

//maximize window

//Implicitly wait 10 sec

//Navigate to URL

//LOCATE THE PATH by xpath by using selecturhub FOR USERNAME and sendkeys

//LOCATE THE PATH by xpath by using selecturhub FOR PASSWORD and sendkeys

I am expecting it should get logged in to the application.

Comment: You should include the full code with the full exception.